# Sinatra on Thin Sever: How to find no. of active connections?

Tags: ruby, connection, sinatra, thin, dashing

I am trying to find out the no. of active connections to my Sinatra App on Thin Server at any given moment

I realize that Thin provides instance method #size to the Class Thin::Backends::Base http://www.rubydoc.info/github/macournoyer/thin/master/Thin/Backends/Base.

But even on doing the following :-

```
puts Thin::Backends::Base.size
```

It is throwing NoMethodError
I am using "dashing" - The Sinatra App built by Shopify

Answer (score 0):

Dashing itself keeps track of the EventSource connections in this: `Sinatra::Application.settings.connections`. If you import sinatra, you should be able to get access to them.

Hope that helps!